# How do i escape a regular expression inside of an array?

Tags: php, regex

Got an array containing regex strings. The idea is to use it with array_filter() on another array. How do i escape the string properly?

```
$rules = [
    '/^foo.bar.*/i',
    '/^baz.*/i'
];
```

Comment: Kinda short on useable info here

Comment: The first slash for example after the quotes. Or any other special character if needed. Or would it work as it is right now?

Comment: be more specific a bit we can't get u...

Comment: there is no special escaping required here - just filter using your regex expressions in the callback function you have to pass to `array_filter()`

Comment: `'/^foo.bar.*/i'`  will match `foo1Barxxxxxxxx   r`. You need to escape the dot here.

Answer (score 0):

Seems no escaping is needed.

```
$rules = [
    '/^foo.bar.*/i',
    '/^baz.*/i'
];

echo $rules['0'] => /^foo.bar.*/i
```

Neat.